# Why are space sizes increased between apostrophes in HTML

Tags: css, html

On my website all of the text between the apostrophes (the words "what's" and "journalist's") have larger spacing than the rest of the text. http://heiditaylorlaw.com/about_me.html Why is this? I tried using the `word-spacing` tag in CSS with no luck.

Comment: A question about an external link document is bad because once it will no longuer exists, this question will no longer be complete. You are better to include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `text-align: justify;`. According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp):

> justify   Stretches the lines so that each line has equal width (like in
>   newspapers and magazines)

However, you can use `text-align:left;` instead of `text-align: justify;`.

Comment: @Yajo100 Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. @alireza-safian